# How to set YUM settings in a Kickstart?

Tags: centos, yum, kickstart

I am moving a 32-bit CentOS server that runs 32-bit applications to 64-bit CentOS to allow more RAM. I already have a kickstart file that I use, but unfortunately the packages listed have no extensions. The result is that I end up with all x86_64 versions of the packages but need the i686 (where available), else I end up with some missing files/inconsistencies.

How can I configure yum within the kickstart to favor installing the i686 over the x86_64 on an x86_64 system?

Upon investigating I've found that in `yum.conf` setting `multilib_policy=all` would cause all available versions to be installed, which would be close enough for my purposes, however the kickstart can not pass yum options. Using a `%pre` install section to inject the config option in the installing image sounds like it would work, but is not a very elegant solution, is there a better way to set this option during an automated install?

My alternative for this would be to script figuring the appropriate extension for all the packages in the kickstart, but I'd favor a config option if it can be relatively clean.

Comment: I've always ended up tacking `.i686` onto 32-bit packages needed on 64-bit systems.

Comment: @thrig I'd rather avoid that mostly because of package groups (which don't have an extension, and often don't have a 32 bit equivalent) and in case additional applications move to this machine I wouldn't have to again append the extension if the 32-bit were available